# Variable not defined - Scope Issue ? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

in the console its giving me the error 'position not defined' using the the code below.. any ideas?

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 1;

function getyx(y, x) {
 var yx = 'Y' + y + 'X' + x ;
 return yx;
}

function getPosition() {
  var position = document.getElementById(getyx(y,x));
 return position;
}

function moveSprite() {
 position.appendChild(img); //error occurs here
}
```

Maybe get element by Id cant accept a function ? 
I know this may be a silly question but forgive me :)

Comment: I think what you need is `GetPosition().appendChild(img);`

Comment: img is not defined anywhere in your provided code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `getPosition` is the function that selects the element you want, so try calling that function:

```
function moveSprite() {
  const position = getPosition();
  position.appendChild(img);
}
```

There's absolutely nothing wrong with passing a string created by a function to `getElementById`

Comment: I've been stuck on this problem for about 3 hours now. You my friend are the man (or woman) ! Thank again

Answer (score 0):

> The reason it is saying position can be a few problems, the simplest being you don't have "Y1X1" as an HTML ID.

Seen as your function returns a string it would be able to use getElementById(). If your not sure about the scope, you can go to the top of your code and use `var position;` however it's most likely not a scope issue.